# pushing objects in a array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to push objects into an array inside a for loop. The expected data structure is

```
[{"valueItem":"item0"}, {"valueItem":"item1"}, {"valueItem":"item2"}, {"valueItem":"item3"}, {"valueItem":"item4"}]
```

The code I have is

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  arr.push(obj.valueItem = 'item'+i);
}

console.log(arr)
```

But the what I get back is

```
["item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats probably happens because you are changing only the item so 
    obj.valueItem = 'item'+i returns only item so adding only it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works ;)

```js
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var obj = {};
  obj.valueItem = 'item' + i;
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: this is 3 lines to achieve arr.push({"valueItem":"item"+i});

Answer (score 2):

try:`arr.push({"valueItem":"item"+i});`

Ok, to clarify, you have to push an object in your array to get your expected array.
push(obj.valueItem = 'item'+i) works sortof because you are assigning inside push.

Comment: yeah that works...but this one what have should work too no?

Answer (score 1):

By doing this `arr.push(obj.valueItem = 'item'+i);`

you are not pushing `obj` into the array, you are making an assignment

`obj.valueItem = 'item'+i`

the result of an assignment is the returned value, in this case it is `item+i`,

to push objects into an array do this

```
arr.push({
  valueItem: "item0"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First define object, then push it to array:

```js
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  arr.push({valueItem: 'item'+i});
}

console.log(arr)
```

Based on your try:

```js
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var obj = {};
  obj.valueItem = 'item'+i
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: yes..I see where I was going wrong. Thanks. This totally works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not actually creating a new object for each loop.  Maybe try:

`arr.push( { valueItem: 'item'+i } );`.

The {} will create a new hash object, which we would push onto the array.

In your inital code you only made one object, so the thing you were pushing was the return value of `obj.valueItem='item'+i`.  Since the return value of a string assignment would be the actual string, you were just creating an array of strings.

Comment: what is a hash object?

Comment: It's a bit redundant in JavaScript because they're the same, but it's just an array where the elements are referred to by name instead of by number.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result has a **different** object for each element.  Even though they are are similar in that they have a valueItem proprerty, they are all different.  So you need to create a new one on each loop iteration.  You need

```
arr.push({valueItem:"item"+i});
```

which creates a new one each time.